# Importing JS bundle to an Angular Library

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-library

I am trying to **add a JS script bundle file to a custom Angular Library** which is using features from it. I have **added the types files so the linting errors are not showing**, but the Project does not get built as classes from JS Bundle are not found.

I have tried and failed importing the bundle to the public-api file.

I am thinking of trying to make the bundle a private npm package to install. But that will take lot of time and effort.
What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you could have that kind of circumtances like having would like to use an JS library in your Angular project.

i have encountered something like that but i have created one directive file in the src folder like "type.d.ts" so after i declared my library in it with something like "declare module 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js';" and at last imported it in my component file like "import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js';"

1- Create one directive file like "type.d.ts"

2- Declare your JS library in your recent file created with something like  "declare module 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js';"

3- Declare back the import statement in your component file like "import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js';"